# Displaying source_location information in a automated way when returning from a function

Tags: c++, c++20

I have two log function to display when I enter and when I leave a function, `void logEnter(const source_location location = source_location::current())` and `void logExit(const source_location location = source_location::current())`, Displayed information are function name and line.

Now I have a function `Foo` which have multiple return statement. I want to call logEnter (with default argument) when I enter the function (easy), and logExit (with default argument) when I return. Problem is, I have to add a call for each return (and if I want to achieve this on many functions, I will be painful).

I was wondering if I could come up with a one-line solution, i.e. similar to a `lock_guard`, just defining some object at the start of the function Foo to achieve this. With a simple class, the problem is that the a destructor cannot take any argument, and it should get the caller source location, not the destructor location.

I do not need to care about exception. To clarify a bit, function Foo is already implemented, so the fewer code I edit, the better it is.

Example:

```
void logEnter(const source_location location = source_location::current()){
  cout << "Log, entering " << location.function_name() <<" at line "<< location.line() << endl;
}

void logExit(const source_location location = source_location::current()){
  cout << "Log, exiting " << location.function_name() <<" at line "<< location.line() << endl;
}

// Working implementation
string parity(int x) {
  logEnter();
  if (x%2 == 0) {
    logExit(); return "even";
  }
  logExit(); return "odd";
}

// Wish implementation
string parity(int x) {
  logFunctionGuard();
  if (x%2 == 0)
    return "even";
  return "odd";
}
```

When calling parity(3), cout terminal should display

```
Log, entering parity at line 10
Log, exiting parity at line 13
```

Comment: misunderstood the quesiton at first. I think it would be good if you could include a small example together with desired output

Comment: how much extra code are you willing to write? Is replacing any `return x;` with `return do_some_magic,x;` an option? How about excpetions? Do you also need `logExit` to be called when the function is left due to an exception?

Comment: Are you tied to `std::source_location`? I can come up with a solution that provides [`std::stacktrace_entry`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/stacktrace_entry) instead

Comment: @Caleth stacktrace_entry is c++23, so unfortunately, in my case it’s not a solution yet, but I guess it could be useful for other people.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a bit cursed, but you can do

```
#define return logExit(); return
```

to automatically add logExit to all return statements. If you only wan't to apply it to Foo, write the macro above of the function Foo and below write

```
#undef return
```

Note however that using a keyword as a macro identifier can lead to UB, as it is a [reserved macro name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace#Reserved_macro_names) as Jarod42 pointed out.

An other option would be to write a simple class

```
class LogExit {
public:
    LogExit(T t, std::source_location sourceLocation = std::source_location::current()){
        cout << "Log, exiting " << location.function_name() <<" at line "<< location.line() << endl;
    }
};
```

Where `T` is the return type of Foo, which is implicitly convertible from `T`. Then change the return type of Foo to `LogExit` and voila. This doesn't work with void and requires you to convert the return value back to `T` if needed.

Otherwise there is [boost stacktrace](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/doc/html/stacktrace.html) then you can define a class with no members and get print the part of the stacktrace which interests you from its constructor and destructor.

Comment: Care with that MACRO, as `if (cond) return 42;` would return unconditionally, but log conditionally...

Comment: indeed, but the space between return and the value makes it difficult, to prevent this. an alternative would be `#define return(x) do {logExit(); return x;} while (0)` but this would require extra brackets for all return statements

Comment: BTW, keywords are [Reserved_macro_names](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace#Reserved_macro_names)

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, added it to the answer

Comment: Somehow, feels like, redefining return with macro is the way to go. Still not really ideal, as it is not really proper C++. Just need to be cautious when there is no return at the end of a void function.

Comment: I do not like the fact to modify return statement adding a class, beside the case of no return value, it seems like adding the logging function call would be equal amount of work.

Comment: With the class approach, you don't need to modify the return statement, just the return type, because the original return value is implicitly convertible to `LogExit`, because the constructor of `LogExit` only takes one argument (t), because sourceLocation is defaulted. Thus changing `T Foo(/*...*/) { /*possibly many returns*/ }` to `LogExit Foo(/*...*/) { /*possibly many unchanged(!) returns*/}` is sufficient.

Comment: `#define return return LogExit(), ` might work for non-void functions to prevent Jarod42's problem. But you need some higher-order shenanigans to make `return;` and `return 42;` work with the same definition. I'm thinking something like `#define return return LogExit(), (MAGIC)` where MAGIC names both a class type and an expression (allowed due to C backwards compatibility).